# Mesh is visible with Dynamic Paint Image Sequence WETMAPS

Tags: dynamic-paint

I am trying to create a fluid scene where the object will have a gloss to simulate wetness after the fluid rolls off the object.

I have the node setup working fine, but the wetmaps for dynamic paint seem to show the mesh lines through it.

can anyone figure out whats going on?

Blend File,
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I2h7YoMSlY9QAkQcvve9KhDY8f0FE0Ss

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't used dynamic paint very much, but my guess is that dynamic paint is doing some of its calculations at a per-vertex level, and because your mesh is low res, this is causing that to be visible. Can you see what happens if you add subsurf before the the dynamic paint modifier and the re-bake it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for commenting. I tried subdivide smooth in edit mode to make the sphere have 5000 faces, the mesh shape though the exported baked wetmap files are smaller but still there. i dont want to inefficiently make this sphere have a stupid number of faces for this, there might be another way to solve this, such as changing format form images to vertex... without using images. Just need to learn how to do that!!

Comment: I have quickly learnt how to use the vertex method and this works based on how complex the mesh is, so if it's low poly, the accuracy is not great, the mesh needs to have plenty of geometry to do this. I might look at photo editing software to maybe blur over the lines?!! haha anyways if anyone has ideas on how to properly use blender image sequence method and not show lines, I'd appreciate your sharing of knowledge